# Cannnot enter console mode on Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS tty2

Tags: boot, display

My friend installed Ubuntu on his HDD and I tried to boot his HDD via USB on my notebook. But My notebook doesn't enter console mode. When I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> my notebook got hanged. I tried to change the display resolution, but it showed:

> Can't open display.

I don't know how to solve this. Please help me how to enter console mode.

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  When you say you "tried to boot his HDD via USB", did it actually boot?  How do you know it booted his HDD via USB and not yours?  Have you tried booting into rescue mode (via grub)?

Comment: I boot it and I could login via terminal mode. But I can’t get into console mode

Answer (score 0):

Some of the devices have different combinations of Keys to enter to the console mode.

As mine is

> Alt + Fn+ Ctrl+ F5

Try combining different keys, and try mine one too.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it